# How Can I Handle Custom Error Message From API?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to handle an error message from API to show as Alert.

E.g When the user tried to add a game to wish list but it's already added before, API returning this error message with 417 status code:

```
{
  "hasError" : true,
  "errorMessage" : [
    "Game is already in your wish list."
  ]
}
```

I want to get this error message from the 'case .failure' to show as Alert in app. Normally It's casting like NSError but I want to handle it like this model:

```
struct ErrorMessage: Codable {
    var errorMessage: [String]
    var hasError: Bool
}
```

I have a HTTPManager :

```
class HttpManager {
    static let shared = HttpManager()

    private init() { }

    enum HttpError: Error {
        case invalidResponse(Data?, URLResponse?)
    }

    public func get(_ url: URL, token: String?, completionBlock: @escaping (Result<Data, Error>) -> Void) {

        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"

        request.setValue("iOS", forHTTPHeaderField: "User-Agent")

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard error == nil else {
                completionBlock(.failure(error!))
                return
            }

            guard
                let responseData = data,
                let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
                200 ..< 300 ~= httpResponse.statusCode else {
                    completionBlock(.failure(HttpError.invalidResponse(data, response)))
                    return
            }

            completionBlock(.success(responseData))
        }
        task.resume()
    }

    public func post(_ url: URL, parameters: [String:Any]?, completionBlock: @escaping (Result<Data, Error>) -> Void) {

        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"


        request.setValue("iOS", forHTTPHeaderField: "User-Agent")

        if parameters != nil{
            guard let httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters!, options: .prettyPrinted) else {
                return
            }
            request.httpBody = httpBody
        }

        //HTTP Headers
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard error == nil else {
                completionBlock(.failure(error!))
                return
            }

            guard
                let responseData = data,
                let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
                200 ..< 300 ~= httpResponse.statusCode else {
                    completionBlock(.failure(HttpError.invalidResponse(data, response)))
                    return
            }

            completionBlock(.success(responseData))
        }
        task.resume()
    }

}
```

And I'm calling API like that:

```
func postWishList(game: Int, platform: Int, completion: @escaping (Result<BaseAddWishList, Error>) -> Void) {

        let url =  baseURL + postWishListURL

        let params =  ["gameId": game, "platform": platform] as [String : Any]

        HttpManager.shared.post(URL(string: url)!, parameters: params) { result in
            switch result {
            case .failure(let error):
                    DispatchQueue.main.async { completion(.failure(error)) }

            case .success(let data):
                do {
                    let res = try JSONDecoder().decode(BaseAddWishList.self, from: data)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async { completion(.success(res)) }
                } catch {
                    print("Unable to retrieve string representation")
                    DispatchQueue.main.async { completion(.failure(error)) }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And my ViewModel Function (I want to receive errorMessage at here for show in an alert)

```
func postWishList(game: Int, platform: Int){
        ApiManager.shared.postWishList(game: game, platform: platform) { [weak self] result in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            switch result {
            case .success(let result):
                print(result)
            case .failure(let err):
                print(err)
// I need errorMessage string at here to show as an Alert.
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: So what is the problem? What is stopping you from showing an Alert?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I want to receive errorMessage at ViewModel .failure case to show in an alert view. I added ViewModel function to the first message, thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

If your server returns 417 for this sort of error, then you’ll have to remove `200..<300` status code check. Then the `dataTask` method can offer more refined checking of status codes:

```
public func post(_ url: URL, parameters: [String: Any]?, completion: @escaping (Result<Data, Error>) -> Void) {
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    request.httpBody = parameters.flatMap { try?JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: $0) }

    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        guard
            let responseData = data,
            let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse
        else {
            completion(.failure(HttpError.invalidResponse(data, response)))
            return
        }

        switch httpResponse.statusCode {
        case 200..<300:
            completion(.success(responseData))

        case 417:  // if there are others, add them to this list
            completion(.failure(HttpError.apiError(httpResponse.statusCode, responseData)))

        default:
            completion(.failure(HttpError.invalidStatusCode(httpResponse.statusCode)))
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Where

```
enum HttpError: Error {
    case invalidResponse(Data?, URLResponse?)
    case invalidStatusCode(Int)
    case apiError(Int, Data)
}
```

---

Then when posting the wish, you can catch this status code and parse the response:

```
func postWishList(game: Int, platform: Int, completion: @escaping (Result<BaseAddWishList, Error>) -> Void) {
    let url =  baseURL + postWishListURL

    let params =  ["gameId": game, "platform": platform] as [String : Any]

    HttpManager.shared.post(URL(string: url)!, parameters: params) { result in
        switch result {
        case .failure(let postError):
            let error: Error

            switch postError {
            case HttpManager.HttpError.apiError(417, let data):
                do {
                    let res = try JSONDecoder().decode(ErrorMessage.self, from: data)
                    error = ApiError.wishFailure(res.errorMessage)
                } catch let parseError {
                    error = parseError
                }

            default:
                error = postError
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async { completion(.failure(error)) }

        case .success(let data):
            do {
                let res = try JSONDecoder().decode(BaseAddWishList.self, from: data)
                DispatchQueue.main.async { completion(.success(res)) }
            } catch {
                print("Unable to retrieve string representation")
                DispatchQueue.main.async { completion(.failure(error)) }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Frankly, if this `ErrorMessage` pattern is used throughout the API, I might move the parsing of errors into `HttpManager`, but hopefully the above is enough to illustrate the pattern.

Comment: Thanks :) I got this when I print error = apiError(417, 71 bytes), how can I use this data that inside of apiError ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can extract that associated value, parse the `ErrorMessage` and then you can present that in the UI. Or if you know that 417 always equals that particular type of error, perhaps the UI would just present the appropriate error messages on that basis.